# Progress bar for a ImageStream doesn't show values from 0 to 1

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, stream, progress

I have a progress bar for a image download in my ASP.NET application.
In a while loop is the following code, in which I divide the length of bytes from the current stream by the expected stream to get the desired progress:

```
if (ExpectedStreamSize.HasValue && _configSize.HasValue)
{
    var expected = ExpectedStreamSize + _configSize.Value;
    var progress = _stream.ReadPosition / (float) expected;
    var limitedProgress = progress > 1 ? 1 : progress;

    var epsilon = 0.001;
    if (!_lastReportedProgress.HasValue || _lastReportedProgress.Value + epsilon < limitedProgress)
        _onProgressChanged?.Invoke(limitedProgress);

    _lastReportedProgress = limitedProgress;
    LogToFile(limitedProgress);     // Logged to see the values
}
```

However, I expect values from `0 to 1`. So from 0% to 100%.
When I debug I get the following value assignments:

```
ExpectedStreamSize.HasValue = true
_configSize.HasValue = 1714

ExpectedStreamSize = 8700000     // 8.7 MB
_configSize.Value = 1714
--> expected: 8701714

_stream.ReadPosition = 1722
expected: 8701714   
--> progress = 0.000197892048
```

I logged the **values for the limitedProgress**, which are the following ones:

```
0,000197892
0,0001981219
0,0001983517
...
0,0004684135
```

But I need the values from 0,00019xxxx to 1,0 (so that I reach the 100%).

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong and how to get the correct progress status?

Comment: What is `ReadPosition` and how is it calculated? And is `ExpectedStreamSize + _configSize.Value` the same as the actual stream size? (code seems fine if these values are correct)

Comment: @JessedeWit Thank you for your effort, I've noted my solution. You are welcome to review it. Was a mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the bug myself and fixed it.

`lastReportedProgress = limitedProgress` of course belongs **in** the if loop, that's wrong otherwise.

The upper solution would probably have worked, but the **time expenditure** would have been extreme, because too many intermediate steps are output and queried here.
Now it works and the log also returns the values I imagined:

```
0,001000033
0,002000066
...
0,9970638
0,998064
0,9990641
```

I also adjusted the **float value** above to make the second condition in the if loop look better.

```
private float _lastReportedProgress = 0;

// some code 

    if(...)
    {
        if (_lastReportedProgress + epsilon < limitedProgress)
    }
```